# Material-UI app bar title styling

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

is it possible to style the AppBar from Material-UI title, not inline way?
I've a css file seperate and I would like to change the size of title for example.

sth like this:

```
.app-bar title {
    font-size: 120px !important;
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. Solution:

```
 <AppBar className="app-bar"
                            title={<div className="app-bar-title">Tomek The Title</div>}
```

and then in css file you can add styles.

Answer (score 1):

try `.app-bar h1` or `.app-bar *` to style css code and then put .app-bar to AppBar Component className

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in docs, http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar component accepts className for wrappper and have h1 tag without class, so you can try:

```
.app-bar h1 {
font-size: 120px !important;
```

}

and

```
<AppBar className='app-bar' />
```

Comment: I solved this but what about the !importants cuz other way it doesn't work, so far it looks like that:

.app-bar {
    background-color: #de6927 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}